# Inserting new event in Google Calendar of a certain user (using PHP API) by running the php script (a CI controller) as a cronjob

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am developing a small application that needs to update certain events (a court hearing) once the initial date changes. The user has the possibility by accessing its application account to manually insert such event in its Google Calendar. Once inserted, the application will monitor any change (against a public API) and once a change occurs it will update the database, will send an e-mail to the user informing about the change and inserting such new event in his Google Calendar.

I am using PHP and CodeIgniter 3.11.

Any change is verified daily against the public API and evidently when the change happens the user is not present in front of his computer. This is made with the help of a cronjob running at a certain hours.

The initial insertion of the event in user's Google Calendar runs ok as is made from the browser manually by the user. But I have problem inserting such event when I run the controller made for monitoring the changes under a cronjob. I am testing it on my own Gmail account.

The cronjob does work, as the controller performs the other two tasks (updating the database and sending the e-mail), without any problem. But updating the calendar never happens. Only if a run the controller again through browser the calendar is updated.The controller that do the monitoring is responsible for setting the oauth url and to redirect to such url. Then I have another control (which stand behind redirect_uri) that should receive the access code and the state.

I have set the access type to offline as google documentation suggests [Google PHP API Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

```
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
```

and I have saved and use a refresh token that can be used for obtaining the access code when user is not present as per google documentation.

It seems to me that when runs as cronjob the controller responsible for updating the calendar (set as redirect_uri in google oauth client configuration) is never reached. This being said my question are:

1. Is it possible to achieve this, i.e. inserting a new event in the google calendar of a user, when user is not present at the browser? Google Documentation implies such possibility, but does not explain in detail how to do it. Quoting the docs:

---

*Requesting offline access is a requirement for any application that needs to access a Google API when the user is not present. For example, an app that performs backup services or executes actions at predetermined times needs to be able to refresh its access token when the user is not present*

---

2. Is my approach, based on using the refresh token, correct, or do I need to perform other tasks in order to achieve the update of the google calendar?
3. How can I find that my controller is redirecting to the google server when runs as cronjob?

   Is there any server log that can check if the redirection set in Monitor.php is working? I have 
   checked apache logs but does not seems to appear any errors. codeigniter logs does not show any 
   errors either.
4. How can I find that the controller responsible for update is reached by the response sent by google 
   server, that have the access code? Is there any way to debug if google response reach the controller 
   behind the redirect_uri?

If you have any other suggestion on how to accomplished this, you are most welcomed.

Many thanks!

Below is some of my code:
Monitor.php (controller run as cronjob)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Class Monitor
 */
class Monitor extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper("utilities", "url");
        $this->load->model("users");
        $this->load->model("files");
        // $this->load->library("portal");
        require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/Portal.php';
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    public function index()
    {
       if (!is_cli()) {
            return;
        }

        $files_query = $this->files->get_all_files();

        if (is_array($files_query)) {
            $files = array();
            foreach($files_query as $file_query) {
                array_push($files, $file_query['file_number']);
            }
            $files = array_values(array_unique($files));
            //print_r($files);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $email_body = "";
                $portal = new Portal($file);
                $portal->set_courtfile_data();
                if (empty($portal->error)) {
                    $court_file = $portal->court_file; //obtaining the court file
                    $termen = $portal->get_last_hearing(); // obtaining the hearing
                    $solutie = $portal->get_solutie(); //obtaining the existing solutions
                    if (is_array($solutie)) {
                        $solutie = $solutie['final'];
                    }
                    $court = $portal->get_court(); //obtaining the court
                    $stadiu = $portal->get_courtfile_stage(); //obtaining the stage
                    if (!$stadiu["apel"]) {
                        $stadiu = $stadiu["stadiu"];
                    } else {
                        $stadiu = $stadiu["apel"];
                    }
        ####--- various checks made against the result retrieve from the public API ---####
        ......
       if ($email_body !== "") {
                $emails = $this->get_user_email($file);
                // Sending the e-mail to the user;

                $template_id = $this->config->item('sendgrid_change_template');
                $dynamic_data = [
                    "file" => $file,
                    "change_body" => $email_body
                ];
                foreach ($emails as $email) {
                    send_grid_email($email, $template_id, $dynamic_data);
                }
                if ($hearing_query) {
                    ###--- function for setting the google auth url ---####
                    $url = $this->set_google_url($court_file); 
                    try {
                        header('Location: ' . $url);
                        //redirect($url);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        log_message('error', $e['message']);
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End of foreach loop
    } else {
        $error = $this->db->error();
        log_message("error", $error["message"]);
    }
}// End of index function

#### -- function used to set the google oauth url ---###
protected function set_google_url($file)
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    try {
        $client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH . 'credentials.json');
        $client->setApplicationName('Monitor App');
        $client->setRedirectUri($this->config->item('update_calendar_url'));
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $client->setState($file);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        return filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('error', $e['message']);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Update_google.php (controller behind redirect_uri)

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Update_google extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper("utilities");
            $this->load->model(array("files", "users"));
            require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $query = $this->users->get_user_by("[user@gmail.com]", "email");
            if ($query) {

                $refresh_token = $query[0]["refreshToken"];
            }
            try {
                $client = new Google_Client();
                $client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH . 'credentials.json');
                $client->setRedirectUri($this->config->item('update_calendar_url'));

                if (isset($_GET['state']) && isset($_GET['code'])) {
                    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
                } else {
                    if ($refresh_token != null) {
                        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
                    }
                }

                    $client->setAccessToken($token);
                    $file = filter_var($_GET['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $query = $this->files->get_file_by($file, "file_number");
                    if (is_array($query)) {
                        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                            'summary' => 'Termen instanță',
                            'location' => $query[0]['court'],
                            'description' => 'Termen în dosarul ' . $query[0]['file_number'],
                            'start' => array(
                                'dateTime' => $query[0]['last_hearing'] . 'T08:30:00',
                                'timeZone' => 'Europe/Bucharest',
                            ),
                            'end' => array(
                                'dateTime' => $query[0]['last_hearing'] . 'T12:00:00',
                                'timeZone' => 'Europe/Bucharest',
                            ),
                        ));
                        $calendarId = 'primary';
                        $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
                    }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                log_message('error', $e['message']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible to insert an event into a user's Calendar, but the user has to give this account access to his Calendar. Have you considered using a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)?

Comment: @Jescanellas The application has access to the Calendar ( I am testing on my gmail account) and it clear appears that has access to insert and modify the calendar. In the API Google Console under Service Accounts header I have a service account which is the Compute Engine service account. Under OAuth 2.0 Client IDs header i have a Service account client generated automatically and required for the project related to my application. Are there any examples how to use such Service Accounts to access Google Calendar when user is not present at the browser?

Comment: Yes, with the Calendar API you can create events and do almost as much as with the user interface without further interaction. Take a look at the code of this [page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#php), which is the Quickstart for PHP. In your case, if the sharing permissions and Service Account is configured properly, changing the credentials of the example to the ones of your Service Account should be enough. Try the Quickstart alone and see if you get any error.

Comment: I have used the Service Account approach but either I receive an Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." }. If i remove this line from my code $client->setSubject("user@gmail") the error is gone but the calendar does not update. I have used this references: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client / https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php /

Comment: What I do not understand from this references is how the Google Service knows the user for which it needs to update the calendar, as the code does not pass any indication to this end?

Comment: the user give access to his gmail account, to my application, in the browser when click a button that insert the initial event. To this end I am using the the OAuth approach. Can this be a problem. Should I use Service Account approach in this situation too?

Comment: That `unauthorized_client` error looks like you are trying to impersonate a user with the Service Account. That is only possible doing Domain Wide delegation with a G Suite Account. To create an event in another user's Calendar they should share it with your Service Account email, and you would need to hardcode their Calendar Ids when running it in the background. If the user has to interact with it, clicking from the browser and then using Oauth should be fine, but it can't be the same code as the Service Account one.

Comment: @Jescanellas The variant requiring interaction of the user, based on OAuth API I have figured it out, and it is working. As an workaround I may include a link in the email notifying the user about the change and the user may use it to update its calendar. But this approach require an extra step from the user.

Comment: @Jescanellas You said "to create an event in another user's Calendar they should share it with your Service Account email". How can I do this programatically? Also I have found this change of Calendar API https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709. According with Google: - Due to a recent change of behaviour, any account has to explicitly "accept" a Calendar that has been shared with them. In case of a Service Account, this "acceptance" should be made by adding the calendar to the CalendarList via CalendarList.insert.

Comment: There is a short example here in Google Documentation https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#php. But I am not quite sure where to put it. I suppose that one option is when I ask the user for the first time to authorize my app. I will give it  a try.

Comment: Hi @LTanase! You are on the right track, please report back with your findings. Just to add some information I'll say that the users can find their calendar ID by going to their Calendar homepage, finding their calendars under *My calendars* and clicking on the right side of it in `⋮ symbol ⮞ Settings and sharing ⮞ Calendar ID (under "Integrate calendar")`. That is the ID that you should use with [`CalendarList.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) on the service account.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to create an event in another user calendar using the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar). I will assume that you don't have a [G Suite account](https://gsuite.google.com/) with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation). In that case, to create an event in another user calendar a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) is needed. You can see [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) an example on how to set up credentials in PHP using Calendar API, you only need to change the example credentials with the ones from your new service account. For the event creation you can use [`Events.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), but remember that the users should have shared the calendar with the service account previously. After they share their calendars you should create them with the previous method using the calendar identifiers. A way for the users to find their calendar identifiers is going into the [Calendar homepage](https://calendar.google.com/), looking at the list of calendars on *My calendars* and clicking on its right side and `⋮ symbol ⮞ Settings and sharing ⮞ Calendar ID (under "Integrate calendar")`. Please, ask me anything if you need further help.

Comment: I have no problem to insert the event in user calendar based on OAuth Api when user is present at the browser. Practically the user will insert the first event in its calendar (a court hearing) by clicking a button in this respect. When this happens he will give access to my application to its primary calendar. The problems appears when i want to update his calendar based on php script running as a cronjob. Evidently in this case the user is not present at the browser and I am not able to insert the new hearing (obtained from a public API) in its calendar using OAuth approach.

Comment: I have tried with a service account but does not work. I receive this error Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } when I am running the php script in the browser although i have created a separate calendar than primary and share it with the application

Comment: I have created a public gist with a snippet of the code that I use in the controller that need to insert the event when user is not present at the browser.https://gist.github.com/ltanase77/3a75725745a38fe6ec03ae3a3ecd85ad